# Is there a kind of OS entropy pool on Windows systems?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, entropy, pseudo-random-generator

I am wondering if Windows provides an equivalent of /dev/urandom from linux ? Or any kind of system entropy pool ?

Comment: The [CryptGenRandom function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because questions about specific security implementations that do not relate to the underlying cryptographic algorithms should be asked on [Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score -3):

So far as I know, Windows does not (but you never know, it has an endless series of APIs so anything is possible). However, Intel hardware does. The Microsoft C/C++ compiler (and the Intel compiler) has intrinsics for obtaining a hardware generated random value. That value is obtained by running two circuits backwards so that are unstable. They generate a ton of very random bits which are then cleaned up. Intel has some white papers on it. I don't know if AMD processors have the same thing. I don't have either the name of the functions or the white paper handy, but you can find them with a web search (or, for the functions, look in the header files).

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the raw output from hardware RNG instructions; best practice is to mix this with other independent sources of entropy. That said, Windows *does* have an API for this, as I mentioned in my comment.